# What is the difference between JSON::Any and JSON::Type in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

In Crystal language, what is the difference between [JSON::Any](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.20.0/JSON/Any.html) and [JSON::Type](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.20.0/JSON/Type.html)? What are the use cases of this types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON::Any [is a struct](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/b0cc6f70f2531e073f76b8e83f8be722e7ec2073/src/json/any.cr#L16), which is returned as a result of parsing. It has convenient methods to access underlying data `as_s`, `as_bool`, `as_f` etc. :

```
obj = JSON.parse %({"access": true})
p obj.class           # => JSON::Any
p obj["access"]       # => true
p obj["access"].class # => JSON::Any
```

`JSON::Type` is an union type of all possible json types. It is used internally by `JSON::Any` struct to [represent the data](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/b0cc6f70f2531e073f76b8e83f8be722e7ec2073/src/json/any.cr#L50):

```
p obj.raw             # => {"access" => true}
p obj.raw.class       # => Hash(String, JSON::Type)
```

Comment: Ok, that's much clearer now. But what I'm still trying to understand, is what the reasoning behind that? Why all `JSON::Type` methods associated with `raw` word? `JSON.parse` returns `JSON::Any`, but `JSON::parse_raw` returns `JSON::Type`. `JSON::Any#raw` returns `JSON::Type` in turn. Maybe it's simple language difficulties, but why Type is Raw?

Comment: You are probably confused by this name conventions. `raw` is an object of type `JSON::Type`. It can be `Bool`, `Int64`, `Float64`, `String`, `Hash`, `Array`, `Nil` etc. (just like possible available types in the json format). It looks logical to me. `JSON::Any` is just a convenient wrapper.

Comment: `JSON.parse_raw` is a method that returns `raw` and doesn't create the wrapper for it. It is simply a more performant analog of `JSON.parse#raw`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Reading through sources made it more clear. `JSON::Any` struct is simply a convenient wrapper for `JSON::Type` data structures.

Answer (score 2):

JSON::Type is a recursively-defined "alias":

```
alias Type = Nil | Bool | Int64 | Float64 | String | Array(Type) | Hash(String, Type)
```

Aliases are part of Crystal's type grammar. For details, see https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/alias.html

JSON::Any is a Struct (Struct < Value < Object); an instance of JSON::Any holds the "raw" value of any JSON type:

```
cr(0.24.1) > x=JSON::Any.new("hi")
 => "hi"
icr(0.24.1) > x
 => "hi"
icr(0.24.1) > x.raw
 => "hi"
```